# Meta Analysis - Find the pooled Odds Ratio, given each subjects OR, Lower and Upper Limit and Z-test values

Tags: meta-analysis, odds-ratio, meta-regression, heterogeneity

I have a problem I have been working on but can't seem to understand how to go about solving, and any help would be most appreciated.

**My Problem:**

I have been asked to find the pooled OR and it's 95% CI, using an inverse approach, and then do a test for heterogeneity.
My data is as follows:

$$OR(1) = 3.150, OR(2) = 5.755, OR(3) = 1.497, OR(4) = 5.380, OR(5) = 6.027$$

$$LL(1) = 1.718, LL(2) = 2.335, LL(3) = 0.676, LL(4) = 3.530, LL(5) = 3.367$$

$$UL(1) = 5.777, UL(2) = 14.184, UL(3) = 3.313, UL(4) = 8.199, UL(5) = 10.788$$

$$Z(1) = 3.708, Z(2) = 3.803, Z(3) = 0.994, Z(4) = 7.827, Z(5) = 6.046$$

where, (OR=odds ratio, LL=lower limit, UL=upper limit, Z=Z-value, (1)...(5)=subject 1-5).

---

I'm unsure whether I'm meant to be using R or hand calculations for the answer, but I have researched online about how to use the heterogeneity test with this kind of data but I am getting no-where.  And I'm really struggling with finding out the pooled OR, as I normally am given the raw data with the weights to be able to calculate $y̅$.

Any help on this would be much appreciated, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work on the log scale. Take the log of the OR. Take the log of each confidence interval limit, subtract the lower from the upper and divide by 3.92 to get the standard error of the log OR. At this point I would recommend using software to proceed further as doing it by hand, although possible, is liable to lead to errors since you have clearly stated you do not know what is going on here. Since you mention R I think the simplest thing is to install either the package metafor or the package meta and read the help. The function you need in metafor is rma.uni(), I am afraid I do not use meta so not sure what the basic function is called there.

Incidentally the method is called inverse variance weighting not just inverse.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation.  Really helped.